# Select apenas retorna resultado no terminal

Tags: python, postgresql, select, psql

Estou com dificuldade em entender o porque que o código abaixo apenas retorna resultado quando executado no terminal.

Pretendo retornar *hash* do últido id inserido na base de dados

```
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname=vone")
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQL = """
  SELECT hash
  FROM pos_order
  WHERE id = ( SELECT max(id) FROM pos_order );"""
cursor.execute(SQL)
hash = cursor.fetchone()[0]
```

Quando executo o códido dentro de uma função, o método `cursor.fetchone()` retorna *none*.

Comment: Coloque na pergunta o SQL `CREATE TABLE pos_order` e uma amostra de dados(formato texto) para testes.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que **o problema esteja em obter a conexão**, pois como você mesmo afirmou, a consulta está funcionado quando consulta por meio do terminal.

**Para solucionar:**
Altere a forma de conexão informando os parâmetros necessários.

```
import psycopg2
connection = psycopg2.connect("dbname='vone' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='123456'")
print(connection)
cursor = connection.cursor()
SQL = """
  SELECT hash
  FROM pos_order
  WHERE id = ( SELECT max(id) FROM pos_order )"""
cursor.execute(SQL)
hash = cursor.fetchone()[0]
print(hash)
```

**Para fins de visualização**, adicionei dois `prints`:

```
print(connection)
...
print(hash)
```